# How to time out grafana session cookie

Tags: grafana

I have the following grafana docker container

```
docker run -d \
-p 3000:3000 \
--name=grafana-kc \
-e "GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000" \
-e "GF_USERS_ALLOW_SIGN_UP=false" \
-e "GF_SERVER_DOMAIN=localhost" \
-e "GF_SECURITY_LOGIN_REMEMBER_DAYS=0" \
-e "GF_SESSION_SESSION_LIFE_TIME=5" \
-e "GF_SESSION_COOKIE_NAME=grafana_sess" \
grafana/grafana:5.2.3
```

I have set the login_remember_days=0 and session_life_time=60 secs. There is absolutely nothing in the container.

I load http://localhost:3000/ in a browser tab and then I close that tab but don't close the browser itself.

What I expect is if go to the browser after lets say 5 mins or an hour and again load http://localhost:3000/ it should prompt me to provide login details instead the user is already logged in. There is no auto refresh.

How can I force grafana to invalidate the grafana_sess cookie after a particular time?

With this configuration the grafana_sess expiration is set to 1969-12-31 which is basically -1 which will be deleted when the browser shuts down. But can I put a expiration time on this cookie?